# post-processing search in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, search

I have an eclipse project with a number of sql queries here and there. 
I wonder if I can perform a search on eclipse for all insert statements in the project, and have eclipse pipe the output into stdout or a file printed in a list format; the file should contain only the search matches and not the project hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In search view menu. Change the search view layout from `Show as Tree` to `Show as List` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all result and paste it to other file or editor.

---

#### Edit:

If you want line number details also then you can use [Eclipse Search CSV Export](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-search-csv-export#.U13x7aaoJk-) plugin.

Comment: in Ecipse Kepler (Build id: 20130919-0819), changing the search view layout into "Show as List" displays the file names but not the search query result lines, while "Show as Tree" does display the query result lines